# BA II Plus - Computation of critical values for f-distribution

Tags: calculation

Can someone use BA II Plus in order to compute critical values in statistics?

If yes could you provide links to material that show how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Most ppl use their phone these days to do simple calcs. There is a free App for Android called Probability Distributions by Matthew Bognar that can compute critical values for common distributions on your phone. BA II App for Android can't do it AFAIK.

Comment: If you use Bognar's app to compte F critical 0.025, 417, 417 you get 1.21194 as expected.